# Kafka won't start with PEM certificate

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka, ssl-certificate, pem

I found that Kafka 2.7.0 supports PEM certificates and I decided to try setting up the broker with DigiCert SSL certificate. I used new options and I did everything like in example in [KIP-651](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-651+-+Support+PEM+format+for+SSL+certificates+and+private+key). But I get the error:

```
[2021-01-20 17:54:55,787] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common for configuration A client SSLEngine created with the provided settings can't connect to a server SSLEngine created with those settings.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:98)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:72)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:157)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.serverChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:97)
        at kafka.network.Processor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:790)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer.newProcessor(SocketServer.scala:415)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$addDataPlaneProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:288)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer.addDataPlaneProcessors(SocketServer.scala:287)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:254)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1$adapted(SocketServer.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer.createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors(SocketServer.scala:251)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:125)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:303)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

*openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -text:*

```
Certificate:
    ...
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
        ...
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
```

I've tried using different versions of Oracle JDK and OpenJDK, but no effect.

I also tried to set certificate with options:

```
ssl.keystore.type=PEM
ssl.keystore.location=/opt/kafka/certs/certificate.pem
ssl.key.password=null
```

And I got а new error:

```
[2021-01-23 20:33:21,552] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Failed to load PEM SSL keystore /opt/kafka/certs/certificate.pem
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Invalid PEM keystore configs
Caused by: java.io.IOException: overrun, bytes = 111
    at javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:92)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$PemStore.privateKey(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:512)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$PemStore.createKeyStoreFromPem(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:462)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$PemStore.<init>(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:435)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedPemStore.load(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:412)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.<init>(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:349)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedPemStore.<init>(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:405)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.createKeystore(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:293)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.configure(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:161)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.instantiateSslEngineFactory(SslFactory.java:136)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:72)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:157)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.serverChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:97)
    at kafka.network.Processor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:790)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.newProcessor(SocketServer.scala:415)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$addDataPlaneProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:288)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.addDataPlaneProcessors(SocketServer.scala:287)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:254)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1$adapted(SocketServer.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors(SocketServer.scala:251)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:125)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:303)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

But if convert this certificate to jks:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -out certificate.p12
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore certificate.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore certificate.jks

echo 'ssl.keystore.location=/opt/kafka/certs/certificate.jks' >>server.properties
echo 'ssl.keystore.password=password' >>server.properties
```

Broker works correctly.

Could this be a bug or am I doing anything wrong? Full log [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/13019123/kafka.log)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might be because the private key you are using is encrypted with a PBES2 scheme. You can use OpenSSL to convert the original key and use PBES1 instead:

```
openssl pkcs8 -in old_kafka.key -passout "pass:password" -topk8 -v1 PBE-SHA1-3DES -out kafka.key
```

You can find more info of which [PKCS#5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898) encryption algorithms are available with PBES1 and PBES2 in [OpenSSL's PKCS#8 man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/pkcs8.html).

Also, PBES2 support in OpenJDK is mentioned in [this issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8231581).

Comment: Then I'd suggest trying RSA keys instead of ECDSA ones if possible. I've configured a Kafka cluster with PEM keys today, so it's definitely possible.

Comment: I use RSA PKCS#5 key and I'm ending up with same problem `Private key could not be loaded`
and `algid parse error, not a sequence`

I read somewhere PKCS#8 with above openssl command but `cannot verify ECDH ServerKeyExchange signature for configuration A client SSLEngine created with the provided settings can't connect to a server SSLEngine created with those settings.`