# Kafka returns "No matching PRIVATE KEY entries in PEM file" when attempting to start using PEM certificates

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, pem

First of all, I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65870378/kafka-wont-start-with-pem-certificate) but it's unrelated and having different issue.

I have the following settings fragment in my Kafka properties file:

```
ssl.keystore.type=PEM
ssl.keystore.key=/path/to/private.key
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain=/path/to/certificate.pem

ssl.truststore.type=PEM
ssl.truststore.certificates=/path/to/ca.pem

ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

Note that `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm` is used because single-server certificate is used for each server in a cluster, therefore I have to bypass SSL hostname verification this way.

When starting Kafka, I am getting the following:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Invalid PEM keystore configs
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:184)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:192)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.serverChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:107)
at kafka.network.Processor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:853)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.newProcessor(SocketServer.scala:442)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$addDataPlaneProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:299)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:190)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.addDataPlaneProcessors(SocketServer.scala:297)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:262)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1$adapted(SocketServer.scala:259)
at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:563)
at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:561)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:919)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors(SocketServer.scala:259)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:131)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:285)
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Invalid PEM keystore configs
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: No matching PRIVATE KEY entries in PEM file
```

Thing is - `private.key`, `certificate.pem` and `ca.pem` are valid files and working with other applications/client libraries. Out of them I used to create keystore/truststore and it works fine. When using keystore/truststore, I've also used these 3 files to connect to Kafka from Python and it worked just fine. I confirm these files are valid and have no issues with other applications.

Also note that private key is `PKCS#8` type, which is expected by Kafka:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify PEM file contents when using PEM store types and `ssl.keystore.key` and `ssl.keystore.certificate.chain` properties:

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.keystore.type=PEM

ssl.keystore.key=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- \
................................................................ \
.........................................= \
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

ssl.keystore.certificate.chain=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- \
................................................................ \
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: If this is the only way - it is ridiculous. I should be able to specify file paths rather than file contents...

Comment: If you want to specify file paths, then you need to use `ssl.keystore.location` and `ssl.truststore.location` properties instead.

Answer (score 8):

The properties for specifying PEM certificates in Kafka are a bit confusing but hope this overview will help. There are two ways to specify certificates in Kafka: as files or as strings (file content).

In both cases you need to specify the following properties:

- `ssl.keystore.type=PEM`
- `ssl.truststore.type=PEM`
- `ssl.key.password=` (empty, if private key is not encrypted)

It is worth reiterating that if the Private Key is encrypted, it must be in the `PKCS#8` format for Java to read it.

### Providing certificates as files

In this case, you want to specify the following properties:

- `ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/file/containing/certificate/chain`
- `ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/truststore/certificate`

The 'trick' here is that the file at `ssl.keystore.location` must contain the following (and in this exact order):

- your private key
- your signed certificate
- any intermediary CA certificates

### Providing certificate content (certs as strings)

If you want to provide the content of the key/certificate/root certificate then you use the following properties:

- `ssl.keystore.certificate.chain=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ...`
- `ssl.keystore.key=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...`

Similarly as above the `ssl.keystore.certificate.chain` should contain the following:

- your signed certificate
- any intermediary CA certificates

Comment: Thanks, this got me most of the way there, but also found this guide useful for some of the details: https://codingharbour.com/apache-kafka/using-pem-certificates-with-apache-kafka/

Answer (score -1):

The problem for me that produced the `No matching PRIVATE KEY entries in PEM` error was that the certificate, key and chain were in PEM format, but base64 encoded.

So in Scala, the solution was applying this:

```scala
  private def decodeBase64(base64: String): String =
    new String(Base64.getDecoder.decode(base64), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```