# How to enable SSL in Kafka server using PEM files?

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I'm trying to configure Kafka 2.8.0 on my development Ubuntu laptop to accept connections over SSL. I found [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-use-pem-certificates-with-apache-kafka-f3b444a00816) blog post about using PEM files in Kafka. I created certificates following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/openssl-self-signed-cert) guide. The generated `domain.crt` file seems to work, at least I can start `openssl s_server` with that file and can connect to this server using `openssl s_client`. However, I have trouble configuring Kafka. My first attempt was this:

```
ssl.keystore.type=PEM
ssl.keystore.location=/home/nar/projects/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/ssl/domain.crt
ssl.key.password=password
```

where `domain.crt` file was the generated certificate and my password was `password`. I got this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Failed to load PEM SSL keystore /home/nar/projects/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/ssl/domain.crt
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Invalid PEM keystore configs
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: No matching PRIVATE KEY entries in PEM file
```

Fair enough, I the blog post mentions that the file at `ssl.keystore.location` need to contain the private key and the certificate, so I concatenated the two files:

```
cat domain_new.key domain.crt >chain.crt
```

and my next configuration attempt was:

```
ssl.keystore.type=PEM
ssl.keystore.location=/home/nar/projects/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/ssl/chain.crt
ssl.key.password=password
```

Unfortunately I still got errors:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target for configuration A client SSLEngine created with the provided settings can't connect to a server SSLEngine created with those settings.
```

I'm kind of lost at this point - what is missing?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68742912/kafka-returns-no-matching-private-key-entries-in-pem-file-when-attempting-to-s ?

Answer (score 1):

Place your certificate authority chain in a truststore file:

```
ssl.keystore.type=PEM
ssl.keystore.location=/home/nar/projects/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/ssl/chain.crt
ssl.key.password=password
ssl.truststore.type=PEM
ssl.truststore.location=cachain.crt
```

This error implies that your domain.crt has a chain of issuing certificates to put in the truststore that is absent. If it's self-signed then put it in the truststore as well as the keystore as you already have.

Comment: Where the `ssl.key.password` was defined/set?

Comment: @PauloOliveira it would have been specified when creating the certificate and key pair. It's optional technically but last I looked the Kafka libraries required the private key to be encrypted with a password.